# Create a figure reference without defining a figure

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I am writing a physics lab and I have a list of figures in the appendix, each figure has a reference. I also have two pages that have handwriting that are to be included in the report, and I want to reference the figures on that page. At the moment, I have to compile, count the references and "Hard code" the numbers of the figures on the handwritten pages.
Is there a way to create references to these figures (in the location they are to appear) without having to actually define a figure, a caption etc?

Comment: We will have to see an MWE here. How are you including the handwritten pages?

Comment: Couldn't you use two dummy figures (tex-side) on a separate sheet, reference them as usual and then add the handwritten ones (glued to another sheet of paper) to the printed copy of your document?

Answer (score 3):

You are going to need something if you don't want to get a bunch of ?? references.  This is about as minimal as possible.

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand{\fakefigure}[1]% #1 = label name
{\refstepcounter{figure}\label{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
As shown in figures \ref{A1} and \ref{A2}, yada yada yada.

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{100}
\appendix\chapter{}
\fakefigure{A1}
\fakefigure{A2}
\end{document}
```